# Flume "Spooling Directory Source" recursive-look for the the files within subdirectories

Tags: flume, subdirectory, spool

I am looking for the Flume "Spooling Directory Source" recursive-look for the the files within subdirectories.
There are some references here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-1899
however since then multiple versions have come out, is there any way we can have recursive directory lookup within subdirectories for the files in Spooling Source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the patch [FLUME-1899-2.patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12703729/FLUME-1899-2.patch) directly.
set the "recursiveDirectorySearch" as ture in your config file.

NOTE: the regex in ignorePattern of config file will also affect the recursiveDirectory folder name. so you might need to modify the code in org/apache/flume/client/avro/ReliableSpoolingFileEventReader.java if you want to ignore the folder name.